# Why is accept() system call not accepting new connection until closing the previous connection socket

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Im designing a multi cleint web server using multithreads in C using Pthreads, i have a Masterthread that is in a loop doing the listening, when there is a connection it spawns a new thread doing a function to serve, while the Masterthread continue listening for connection.

as i have notice from debuging, its serving only one connection at a time, the Accept() system call is waiting for that connection to close, then it will spawn the next connection in the queue.

Its acting like if its a single-thread web server.

```
    void *ServeThread(void *param)
{    int tsk;
     tsk = (int)param;

    /* here im serving the connection (tsk), and then close it */
}

void *MakeThreadPool(void *param)
{

    for(;;) {
        length = sizeof(cli_addr);
        if((socketfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &length)) < 0) { 
            exit(1);
                                                  }
    temps=socketfd;
    rc = pthread_create(&Thread[i++],NULL,ServeThread,(void *)temps);

                        }
}
```

How can i make accpet() contine listening al spawning theads when ever there is a connection without waiting for the previous one to finish ?

Comment: Your analysis is wrong, this code will not wait for an existing connection/thread to finish. Though it's possible you influence this by debugging the app (perhaps all threads are stopped while you step around in the debugger). Find another way to debug this, (e.g. with simple printfs), and/or show some more code, and describe how you test this.

Comment: Is the socket in NONBLOCKING mode?

Comment: i removed the close(socket), and i connected to web server with a web browser and entered the web server URL, and i opened a new tab and also connect the web server. and only one of the tabs is connecting " of course it didnt close the connection" but the other one is waiting " there is no (transfering data message in the tab) " like the connecting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You observation is not correct, `accept(2)` does not wait for established TCP connection to complete. What you see is probably thread dispatch artifact - the main thread is preempted by the newly spawned thread and does not get to run until that one completes.

In general, thread-per-connection is a workable strategy, but you might want to create a pool of threads before accepting connection, instead of starting a new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `malloc` to put the file descriptor in it - this will prevent the race condition that you are experiencing. The newly created thread has the contract to `free` this when done. Alternatively (and a nicer solution) is to have a pool of threads that are ready to go. Use a mutex and a queue so they can pick them off when ready to process.

Better still and probably simpler to implement, create a bunch of threads - each one has a mutex around the `accept`. The main thread could top up this list if necessary or ask some to terminate gracefully if there are *too* many.

Answer (score 0):

TCP socket is blocking by default. Have you set those flags ?

```
  x=fcntl(socket,F_GETFL,0);            
  fcntl(socket,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);
```